# How do native speakers think about phrasal verbs?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I would like to ask a question about phrasal verbs.

Do native english speakers think about the meaning of each individual word of the phrasal verb when they will say it or they just think about the meaning of the entire phrasal verb?

Example:
You will say: Yesterday I came up with a brilliant idea.
Do you native speaker think about the verb "**come**" and that you have to put "**up**" after that and before the object(a brilliant idea) you have to put "**with**"... Or do you just think "**come up with**" like if it was just one word with the meaning it has?

If I didn't made myself clear, please let me know.

**Thank you all**.

Comment: Like it was just one word.

Comment: We often gloss over them without much throught.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. Mine is that we do not always think about possible synonymity as we speak. I come up with (conceive) the answer that we put up with (tolerate) them.

Comment: Some thoughts derived from the individual words in a phrase may unavoidably arise, e.g. 'running around town' can mean 'acting promiscuously' but can make one think of jogging or something like that, but it does not obscure the correct context-reinforced interpretation.

Comment: Thank you all so much.